# Why doesn't this cause an array out of bounds error in Python?

Tags: python

I do not know much about python, but I am surprised the following code works:

```
import sys
prev =  [sys.maxint]*(5)
j = 0
print prev[j]
print prev[j-1]
```

In general I thought second `print` statement should give me an error. Why does this work?

I need to convert some `python` code into `C++`, and in `C++` this will not work.

Comment: Next question: [Good Primer for Python Slice Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mylist[-1]` returns the last item of `mylist`, `mylist[-2]` the second-to-last item etc.

This is by design. Read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Answer (score 2):

That's because j - 1 evaluates to -1, which when used as index of python list, means last element.

Answer (score 2):

The index of an array `l` can be an integer in the range `[-len(l), len(l)-1]` (note: inclusive on both ends).  You are familiar with the indices in the range `[0, len(l)-1]`.  The indices in the range `[-len(l),-1]` are as follows: take `i` in that range, then `l[i] == l[len(l) + i]`.  Essentially, negative numbers count backwards from the end of the array.

Thus, `prev[j-1] = prev[-1] = prev[len(prev) + -1] = prev[5 - 1] = prev[4]`, or the last element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

In python x[-1] returns the last element in a list